# Firefox/Chrome etc not under the 'Run' tab in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I was fiddling with Notepad++'s preferences in order to change the looks and a few other things. I'm not sure what I did, but now the *'Run in Chrome'* etc options aren't in the 'Run' tab.

For example, the options found here:

[image: Notepadd++ 'Run' Tab showing the Launch in 'browser' options]

I've tried uninstalling and restarting my computer. All I had was Notepad++ was still in my start tab shortcuts but the icon was not a pic of Notepad++, but instead a white scroll/white script.

I clicked it and says the program is not in my computer. It asked me if I wanted to delete the shortcut and I clicked OK. It still did not delete it.

I went and downloaded the new Notepad++, but there's still no *'Run in Chrome'* option in the Run tab, and the icon is still the white scroll instead of the Notepad++ icon.

Comment: What does notepad and Chrome have to do with one another?

Comment: No i mean like usually i run my notepad from the run tab.. but now the run tab does not have the run in chrome or run in firefox or run in ie.

Comment: If you use F5 on in Notepad++ or Run... you can browse to Chrome or Firefox and it should launch in the selected browser. Make sure you've downloaded the correct Notepad++: http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: Ill try pressing f5. The run button doesnt work. I pressed it and founs the firefox. Pressed run but it didnt run. Ill try pressing f5 when i open my computer

Comment: You can check whether the option "Launch in firefox or launch in chrome are available in the "Modify Shortcut/Delete command menu" by going through "Menu -> Run -> Modify Shortcut/Delete command".

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [How to get (back) option in Notepad++ to run in a web browser](https://superuser.com/questions/592182/how-to-get-back-option-in-notepad-to-run-in-a-web-browser)

Comment: @DanialSaufi - I've added a picture of the commands, can you confirm if these are the items you're missing?

Answer (score 0):

Im having the same issue, the only solution i've figured out is clicking file and open in default viewer. It should run in your default browser.